# Is [pathing] a synonym of [path-finding]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request, clean-up

I've just come across a question about pathfinding (you know, Dijkstra, A*, that sort of thing) that had the tag [pathing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathing) instead of [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding).

The [pathing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathing) tag has no tag wiki. There are [62 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathing) tagged [pathing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathing) and most seem to be about pathfinding, though some are about the "path" i.e. the location in a file system.

Should [pathing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathing) be made a synonym of [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding), or should these questions be re-tagged to either [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding) or [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path)?

And should the [pathing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathing) tag be burninated, or is there a specific subject that the [pathing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathing) tag was created for?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "pathing" isn't even a real word. I say we burn it.

Comment: Verbification is a problem in English.  Or verbing if you prefer :)  [path-finding] is fine, too bad it got exposed to dashification.  Or dashing if you prefer.  You shouldn't.  I tried to create the synonym but I don't have 5 rep in the tag.  Who does.  Lovely how the site keeps reminding me that 700K rep isn't enough yet.

Comment: @HansPassant I considered that "pathing" (pronounced like "bathing" or "scathing") could be a play of words on "paving", and mean pathfinding by laying tiles in a square grid. But probably not.

Comment: "Pathing" is a common term for pathfinding in the context of video games, though it's also used in other contexts, and it has other (mostly related) meanings.

Comment: Wiktionary references: [pathing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pathing) and [pathfinding](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pathfinding). _path-finding_ doesn't exist on this open and collaborative dictionary.

Comment: @HansPassant: Every time I have to interact with tag synonymization I'm reminded how lolbroken it is, and I cringe.

Comment: Pathing is even given as a synonym of pathfinding on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding). I agree that this usage makes me cringe, but I guess a tag synonym is appropriate here.

Comment: @Cœur Wiktionary's example of "career pathing" probably means that "pathing" was invented by McKinsey consultants.

Comment: @CodyGray Urban Dictionary says "pathing" means "peeing while bathing", so there's that too. :-)

Comment: A related question which extends this one:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409256/duplicate-tags-for-path-finding-pathfinder-path-finding-and-pathing-qui