# Duplicate tags for path finding: [pathfinder] [path-finding] and [pathing] - quite similar and confusing

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, clean-up

This question actually extends a question posted a year ago:
[Is [pathing] a synonym of [path-finding]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352592/is-pathing-a-synonym-of-path-finding)

I'm adding a third tag [pathfinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder) to it, which, like [pathing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pathing), has no tag wiki and is used by only 68 questions.

There are similar questions under all 3 tags. I find it confusing– what can be done about it?

Comment: Do any of this tag has any purpose other than existing for the librarians?

Comment: @Braiam Someone can be an expert on pathfinding and pathing, and a python pathfinding problem could help someone writing pathfinding in C++.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont why isn't [python] enough? And if it's so special, why not create a [python-pathfinding]? Don't python have libraries for this?

Comment: @braiam Programming is not just about "find a library that already solves the problem"?  And 90% of the difficulty of writing pathfinding code that isn't "someone already did it for you" isn't language specific.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont which then moves us to the problem that those issues seems more about high level math than practical programming. I'm sure there are ready to be used pathing algorithm that people have problem implementing. They don't need a tag for that.